Angular - AuthGuard not working after refresh
I'm using AuthGuard in Angular, and I've encountered an issue. When I log in successfully, the HomeComponent renders. However, when I refresh the page, HomeComponent doesn't render.
app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginButtonComponent } from "../components/login-button/login-button.component";
import { SidebarComponent } from '../components/sidebar/sidebar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, LoginButtonComponent, SidebarComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Formatier';
}

I'm using Angular version 18.2.0 and Auth0 Angular SDK version 2.2.3.

What code do you have in your auth guard?

I use AuthGuard from '@auth0/auth0-angular'

It sounds like the login session is not persisted across a page refresh, hence the Auth0 guard thinking that you're not logged in anymore. Are you saving the user session to a cookie or local storage?

No, I'm not saving the user session to a cookie or local storage.

There are some notes here from the Auth0 website on this issue: https://community.auth0.com/t/why-is-authentication-lost-after-refreshing-my-single-page-application/56276

sounds like you're using global window vars for session state.  Those will be deleted when refreshing the page.  Shouldn't authguard redirect to login, though?  (when checking canActivate?)

My issue has been resolved by adding cacheLocation: 'localstorage'. Thank you everyone for your advice.

I'm Thai and My English isn't good.

I need the AuthGuard to send users to the login page if they're not logged in.
